# How to connect Aurora PostgreSQL servreless instance using python?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

I have created Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL compatibility and know I want to connect that Database and insert and fetch data but I'm unable to connect my AWS Aurora PostgreSQL using python...

My Code:

```
def connection_maker(self):
    try:
        ENDPOINT = "assetsintel.cluster-cjeiapuahe69.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
        PORT = 5432
        USR = "postgres"
        REGION = "us-east-1"
        DBNAME = "assetsintel"
        PASS= "ScottRocks2020!*"

        # gets the credentials from .aws/credentials
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
        client = session.client('rds')
        print(f'Client: {client}')

        token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USR, Region=REGION)
        print(f'Token: {token}')

        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect(host=ENDPOINT, port=PORT, database=DBNAME, user=USR, password=token,
                                    sslmode='prefer', sslrootcert="/home/mobin/Downloads/boston_mobin_lus_.pem")
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
            query_results = cur.fetchall()
            print(f'Query results: {query_results}')
        except Exception as e:
            print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))

        return None
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error(f'in Creating connection ! {error}')
```

I got stuck after toker printing:

Error:

```
Database connection failed due to could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "assetsintel.cluster-cjeiapuahe69.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.10.129) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: you have to goto the security group of the rds and allow incoming connections from the application. have you done that part? where are you running the python code.

Comment: @ArunK I'm running my code on a local machine on ubuntu and yes I have done that inbound and outbound traffic allow...

Comment: This is not a python program problem. this is a network issue. thats why I posted an answer for you. Start with the rds instance. check whether the rds instance is configured to be publicly accessible. then get to the subnets and see if the subnets has a route to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the host name `x.cluster-y.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` is resolving to a private ip address ('172.31.xx.xx'). Private Ip addresses can only be accessible with in its own network.

What may have happened here is, when you created the RDS instance, you must have created it as a private instance. Therefore the RDS instance is not reachable over the internet.

Here are some tips to troubleshoot.

- RDS instance it self configured as publicly accessible
- Make sure the VPC has an internet gateway associated.
- The RDS DB subnets should have a route to internet gateway
- Finally, The RDS security groups should allow traffic from your home IP

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/) is the AWS official guide to troubleshoot.

Comment: Okay, let me try and after writing the whole script I'll dockerize and run this script on AWS so what I have to do for that...Do I need to add docker network ip...

Comment: you can run the docker inside an EC2 instance or Fargate etc.  The better approach is to goto the RDS's security group and allow the traffic from the EC2 instance's security group. or you can allow a whole subnet. All the recommendations I gave above is about accessing the RDS from your local computer. You can already access the RDS within the aws VPC if inbound rules allows that.